# How to run all integers in an array through an equation and append to a new array with a for loop?

Tags: numpy

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but I want to take an array of values from -80 to 0, and sub them into an equation where the missing variable, T, takes each of those values from the first array and then runs the equation with that and makes a new array. See code below:

```
T = np.arange(-80, 2, 2)
empty = []
esw = 6.11*np.exp(53.49*(6808/T)-5.09*np.log(T))

i = 0
for i in range(T):
    6.11*np.exp(53.49*(6808/T[i])-5.09*np.log(T[i]))
    x = np.append(empty)
    i = I+1
```

I know this is probably some miserable code, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The line `6.11*np.exp(53.49*(6808/T[i])-5.09*np.log(T[i]))` isn't saved to any variable. It's just calculated and then nothing happens. Nothing happens to the `empty` list during the `for` loop, so appending `empty` to `x` does nothing. You shouldn't increment `i` in your loop - Python does this automatically. You need to use `for i in range(len(T))` in order to get indices (`T[i]` is indexing, so `i` needs to be an index, not a value of `T`). Also, since you have negative values in `T`, the step `np.log(T)` (or `np.log(t[i])`) will throw an error.

Comment: T takes negative values or 0, thus the log (`np.log(T)`) is either undefined or infinite.

Comment: There's no point in assigning a value to the iteration variable in a loop. `i = I+1`.  The `for` assigns that value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have taken the liberty of doing a bit of math to hypothetically make your `esw` possible with negative numbers *when the exponent is an integer*, though it still won't work when `T = 0` because of the division in the exponent. Note that because your exponent is `5.09`, the code still doesn't work with negative `T` values. We now have:

```
esw = 6.11 * np.exp(53.49*6808/t) / t**(5.09)
```

where `t` is some value in your `T` array of values.

If you're trying to get `esw` for each value in `T`, you can structure your code in 2 main ways. The non-vectorised way, which is to loop through every value of `T` with a `for` loop and is a safer method, looks like this:

```
# If the calculation cannot be done, None will be returned.
def func(t):
  try:
    esw = 6.11 * np.exp(53.49*6808/t) / t**(5.09)
  except:
    esw = None
  return esw

# new_arr is the same size as T. Each value in new_arr is the corresponding value of T
# put through the esw calculation.
new_arr = np.apply_along_axis(func, 0, T)
```

Note that for the values of `T` you chose (between -80 and 2), all `esw` values are either `None` or infinity.

If your calculations were possible (i.e. all your `T` values were > 0), you could vectorise your code (a good idea because it's easier to read and also faster), like so:

```
new_arr = 6.11 * np.exp(53.49*6808/T) / T**(5.09)
```

This method is less safe because as soon as an error is encountered, the program crashes instead of returning `None` for that value in `T`. With your `T` values, this code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic Python errors, suggesting that you haven't read much of a Python intro, and haven't learn to test your code (step by step).

You create an array, e.g.:

```
In [123]: T = np.arange(-3,2)
In [124]: T
Out[124]: array([-3, -2, -1,  0,  1])
```

and try to iterate:

```
In [125]: for i in range(T):print(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [125] in <cell line: 1>
    for i in range(T):print(i)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

In [126]: range(T)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [126] in <cell line: 1>
    range(T)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

`range` takes a number, not an array.  It's a basic Python function that you should know, and use correctly.  You can get a number by taking the length of the array or list, `len(T)`:

```
In [127]: range(len(T))
Out[127]: range(0, 5)
In [128]: list(_)
Out[128]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You do a `i=0` before, and some sort of assignment to `i` in the loop, which means you don't understand (or care) about how the loop assigns `i`.

```
In [129]: for i in range(4):
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     i = i+10
     ...: 
0
1
2
3
```

Adding `10` to `i` did nothing; the `for` assigns the next value from the `range`.  Again this is basic Python iteration.

As for the `empty` and `np.append`:

```
In [130]: empty=[]
In [131]: np.append(empty)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [131] in <cell line: 1>
    np.append(empty)
  File <__array_function__ internals>:179 in append
TypeError: _append_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'
```

The correct way to use list append is:

```
In [132]: alist = []
     ...: for i in T:
     ...:     alist.append(i*2)
     ...: 
In [133]: alist
Out[133]: [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2]
```

List append works in-place, and it is reasonably fast.  `np.append` is a poorly name function that should not exist.  It is not a list append clone.

Since `T` is an array, we don't need to iterate.

```
In [134]: T*2
Out[134]: array([-6, -4, -2,  0,  2])
```

An alternative to the list append loop is a list comprehension.  It's a bit faster than the iteration, though not as fast as the direct array calculation.

```
In [135]: [i*2 for i in T]
Out[135]: [-6, -4, -2, 0, 2]
```

Finally, that line

```
6.11*np.exp(53.49*(6808/T[i])-5.09*np.log(T[i]))
```

in the loop does nothing; not even assign a value to a variable (as you did outside the loop with `esw=...`.  Did you really think it did something? Or was this just a careless mistake?